# Apply image/pattern to pie section instead of normal color

Tags: java, jfreechart

Instead of using normal `plot.setSectionPaint()` method to fill color of the pie section, is it possible to add a pattern or a image as shown below.

I have got this requirement as the colors are difficult to distinguish when printed in black & white printer.

Worst case if not possible then I will have to use 2 very different colors which are easily distinguishable over b/w printer

[image: pie chart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`setSectionPaint`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/PiePlot.html#setSectionPaint-java.lang.Comparable-java.awt.Paint-) allows any implementation of the interface [`java.awt.Paint`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Paint.html) to be passed. `Color` is one class that implements `Paint`, but there are others, such as [`TexturePaint`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/TexturePaint.html).

This code will create a `TexturePaint` like the blue line pattern in your example:

```
BufferedImage texture = new BufferedImage(1, 30, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D g = texture.createGraphics();
g.setColor(Color.white);
g.fillRect(0, 0, 1, 30);
g.setColor(new Color(0x26A2D6));
g.fillRect(0, 0, 1, 20);
g.dispose();

TexturePaint texturePaint = new TexturePaint(texture,
    texture.getRaster().getBounds());
```

You can then pass that `texturePaint` as the argument to `setSectionPaint`.

Comment: You are simply amazing! I can't thank you more. You must be a Java guru for sure